# Redirect all unfound links for a third level domain to site index for each language

Tags: redirect, 301-redirect

I need to redirect all unfound pages for each language. 
I've created a redirect for third domain level en.mysite.it to www.mysite.it/en/ 
Now I need to understand how to redirect each en.mysite.it/page.html page not found, to www.mysite.it/en/.
This is the code I'm using in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.mysite\.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.en\.mysite\.it$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mysite\.it\/en\/" [R=301,L]
```

I've multiple redirects for each language, so i need to redirect only pages from the subdomain "en" and repeat the code for each language.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Founded... 
Need to replace only this `^/?$`  with that  `^(.*)`

The result:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.mysite\.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.en\.mysite\.it$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule `^(.*)` "https\:\/\/www\.mysite\.it\/en\/" [R=301,L]
```